# How to Write False Positive/Negative Tests? (for Jasmine or similar)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, assertion, false-positive

**Is it possible to capture the pass/fail results of a Jasmine assertion and run assertions on the result before it hits the reporter?**

I am currently working on an internal test framework that wraps Jasmine and a few other tools into a single internal test framework/harness. To confirm my wrappers don't produce false negatives or positives, I want to be able to run assertions against the results of those assertions to ensure they are correct.

In an ideal scenario, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```js
let failWrapper = () => {
    fail("This spec is flagged to fail") // Invokes Jasmine fail method
}

...

it("wrapper function returns a test failure condition", ()=>{
    let result = captureAssertionResult(failWrapper()) // Results go to this variable, not the html or terminal reporter
    expect(result).toBe(false) // Reporters mark this as a passing test
})
```

or

```js
let equalWrapper = (a,b) => {
    expect(a).toBe(b) 
}

...

it("wrapper function returns a test failure condition", ()=>{
    let result = captureAssertionResult(equalWrapper(0,1))
    expect(result).toBe(false)
})
```

Where `captureAssertionResult` would convert a Jasmine pass/fail result into a boolean.

Comment: have you tried with `try..catch`?

Comment: @DanielA.White Just did, doesn't work.